# Find overlapping ranges in Algolia?

Tags: elasticsearch, date-range, algolia

How would you search Algolia for overlapping numerical ranges?

For example (my use case), I'm working with events on a calendar. Each event has a `date` and and `endDate` and I'm trying to find all events that fall in a month. Right now I'm searching using 'numericFilters` like this:

```
{
  ...
  "facetFilters":"...",
  "numericFilters":"[[
    \"date:1517472000000 TO 1524985199999\",
    \"endDate:1517472000000 TO 1524985199999\"
  ]]"
}
```

This gives me all events that begin or end during a month. But what about events that start last month, and end next month. How do I search for those?

Comment: `or any elasticsearch`: Algolia is not based on ElasticSearch. The solution will likely be different for each search engine.

Comment: I stand corrected. I thought algolia and elasticsearch worked similarly.

Comment: No problem :) If you want to learn more about how Algolia is built, check out the blog series **[Inside the Algolia Engine](https://blog.algolia.com/inside-the-algolia-engine-part-1-indexing-vs-search/)**!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how you would do this with elasticsearch, however with Algolia this is the right approach. Removing the filtering on `date`, you could get all events that started anytime and end in this month:

```
"numericFilters":"[[
  \"endDate:1517472000000 TO 1524985199999\"
]]"
```

But if you want all events that are **happening during a month**, so that started *before or during* that month and end *during or after* it, you would filter to remove those that **start after the end** of the month and those that **end before the begin** of the month:

```
"filters":"date < 1524985199999 AND endDate > 1517472000000"
```

Comment: Genius. That's exactly what I needed.